# Undefined index errors (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting notices of an undefined index "id" on lines 3, 6 and 7 in this code. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
    if ( isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'save' ) {
    foreach ($options as $value) {
        if(($value['type'] === "checkbox" or $value['type'] === "multiselect" ) and is_array($_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]))
            { $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]=implode(',',$_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]); //This will take from the array and make one string
            }
        $key = $value['id'];  
        $val = $_REQUEST[$key];
        $settings[$key] = $val;
    }
```

I'm thinking this is a small thing to fix but haven't had any luck with anything I've tried. One thing I did do is run var_dump($key) and sometimes $key is null and sometimes it's not. So I'm assuming it has to do with this.

This is part of an options page for a WordPress theme, by the way. This is the code that runs as part of the "save" function.

The script actually works properly if debug mode is turned off, but when debug mode is on, these notices pop up when hitting the save button on the options page. Thanks in advance for any insights, and let me know if I need to post more code to give more context.

EDIT: I've posted the options page in pastebin. It's long. It contains t13lo's fixes. The problem code is on line 1957. Thanks: http://pastebin.com/NGX6qzgr

Comment: I think you deserved a downvote from me, what is line 1 does ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "what is line one does"...did I do something wrong? Are you asking what line 1 does? It's supposed to be saving the options... I'm new to programming, also, so if I've done something really stupid, let me know!

Comment: I'm sorry, could you give a little more detail? I'm a novice, lol!

Comment: @orbit82, you have three opening braces, but only two closing braces.

Comment: @Geoffrey Van Wyk  - I didn't post all of the code, only the relevant code, so that explains the missing closing brace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1):

You can change line 3 to:

```
if ( ($value['type'] === "checkbox" || $value['type'] === "multiselect" ) && isset($_REQUEST['id']) && is_array($_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]) )
```

However, the rest of your code in your foreach seems dependent upon `$value['id']`. This value is not always being set so it may make these lines:

```
$key = $value['id'];  
$val = $_REQUEST[$key];
$settings[$key] = $val;
```

Irrelevant if `$value['id']` is not set. If that's the case, placing all of the code that is currently in the foreach within an `if (isset($value['id'])) {` may be appropriate.

You'll need to further analyze and understand what the code is (and needs to be) doing in order to determine the correct logic.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @webbiedave and @Mathias E, but it didn't have any effect. I get the same errors...

Comment: Thanks, so much for your suggestions. I tried putting the foreach block within an if(isset[$value['id']) and while that stopped the errors, the options are no longer being saved to the database, no matter if they're set or not. Is there a way to check if an option has been set, yet save it no matter what? Why does it work properly without the isset checks, but it doesn't work with the isset checks?

Comment: @orbit82, maybe you could post the options form so we could test it on our computers.

Comment: I could post the entire form, but it probably won't run on its own because it needs to be in a wordpress environment. I'll post just the form in pastebin, however, so maybe you can see the entire thing (warning it's quite long).

Comment: @Geoffrey Van Wyk, I've edited my question to include a link to the full code.

Comment: This is huge. I don't think I will be able to test it.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I didn't want to post it before, lol. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Have no idea what your code is suppose to be doing, but based on what you've posted give this a shot.. (replacing obviously just the foreach loop part of your code)..

```
foreach ($options as $value) {
    if( !isset( $value['id'] ) )
        continue;
    if( !isset( $_REQUEST[$value['id']] ) ) {
        $settings[$value['id']] = '';
        continue;
    }
    if( $value['type'] === "checkbox" || $value['type'] === "multiselect" ) { 
        // No isset check here, the top conditional catches non-set items
        if( is_array( $_REQUEST[$value['id']] ) )
            $_REQUEST[$value['id']] = implode( ',', $_REQUEST[$value['id']] );
    }
    $settings[$value['id']] = $_REQUEST[$value['id']];
}
```

Should do exactly the same as before, with exception to checking vars are set first, at also setting a value in the $settings array to an empty string when the matching $_REQUEST var isn't set.. (assuming i'm following what the code is doing correctly that is)..

**EDIT:** *Following discussion in comments i've updated the code above, that should fix the notice on line 1957. It makes sense for that key not to be set for your code, not all the array items in `$options` are actually options, some refer to headings/tabs(whatever) that get output on your theme's options page(so it makes sense to skip them in the loop above).*

I think that will solve your problem, but having said that i think it's important to point out that the code in that function is not ideal, the whole saving mechanism doesn't look very well sanitized overall. I'd be inclined to suggest setting the required capability for that page to `manage_options` so it's restricted to administrators at least until such time a replacement can be put in place(suggestions for which should be in a seperate question, and ideally on [WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/)).

Comment: Wow, thanks this almost works! Except when I save, I get a warning that index id is undefined on this line: if( !isset( $_REQUEST[$value['id']] ) ) {
        $settings[$value['id']] = '';
        continue;
    }
The code is part of a WordPress theme options panel. This part of the code is responsible for saving options to the database. The notices show up upon saving with debug mode on.

Comment: Ok, well that can be fixed easily, do the options save correctly though?

Comment: Hey, thanks  for your help, but I've resolved the issue! I'll update the question with the fix!

Comment: Updated my answer, added fix for the error on line 1957, and some general comments, happy to help in any case.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if(($value['type'] === "checkbox" || $value['type'] === "multiselect" ) &&  isset($value['id']) && is_array($_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ])){ ...
```